# How to format text replies with ">" prefix

Tags: thunderbird

I sometimes receive an HTML email that I want to reply to as text with a ">" prefix.

When I do a text reply what Thunderbird does is prefix the entire paragraph with a single ">".  For example:

```
> Mozilla Thunderbird is a free and open-source cross-platform email client, personal information manager, news client, RSS and chat client developed by the Mozilla Foundation. The project strategy was originally modeled after that of the Mozilla Firefox web browser.
```

Is there a setting in Thunderbird that would produce this:

```
> Mozilla Thunderbird is a free and open-source cross-platform
> email client, personal information manager, news client, RSS
> and chat client developed by the Mozilla Foundation. The
> project strategy was originally modeled after that of the
> Mozilla Firefox web browser.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
fmt -w 65 file |sed  -e 's/^>//' -e  's/^/>/'
```

sample output:

```
>Mozilla Thunderbird is a free and open-source cross-platform
>email client, personal information manager, news client,
>RSS and chat client developed by the Mozilla Foundation. The
>project strategy was originally modeled after that of the
>Mozilla Firefox web browser.
```

Comment: I know how to format text as described, but I'm looking for a way for Thunderbird to do that for me when I press "Reply".